# Is there a Javascript event fired when currentSrc for an <img> tag changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Suppose I have an `<img>` tag:

```
<img id="my_tag" src="/default.jpg" srcset="/small.jpg 500w, /medium.jpg 1000w, /large.jpg 2000w">
```

When I load the page, JavaScript can tell me which of the `srcset` it is using:

```
document.getElementById("my_tag").currentSrc
```

How can I detect when `currentSrc` changes and fire an event?

To stave off the cries of "duplicate!" I can confirm that it doesn't fire in Chrome using DOM MutationObserver [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22736833/1496552), using [jQuery observe](https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe), or using the `onload` event:

```
var my_tag = document.getElementById("my_tag");
my_tag.onload = function(){
    alert("CHANGED");
    console.log( "Src changed to " + my_tag.currentSrc );
};
```

I think this is because when `srcset` is used it doesn't seem to update the DOM when currentSrc changes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [firing event on DOM attribute change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'onload' event of the image:

```
var my_tag = document.getElementById("my_tag");
my_tag.onload = function(){
    console.log( "Src changed to " + my_tag.currentSrc );
}
```

A related post on [Cross-browser image onload event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403983/cross-browser-image-onload-event-handling)

Comment: @awidgery yes I tested it in Chrome 42. When a new image loads the onload event fired.

Comment: @awidgery are you sure the src is changing? You haven't specified  sizes i.e. `sizes="50vw"`

Comment: What if you want to measure when the `currentSrc` changes but before the image has loaded? This might be useful if you want to show a loading indicator, for example. You would need a way to know when the image request starts and stops—and `currentSrc` can change at any time, e.g. on resize, or if `sizes` is changed.